# Host Bokeh(Python) to Windows Server

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-deployment, bokeh

I have developed an app using bokeh(Python). App is working fine when I run this on my local machine using localhost:5006/myapp. I have Windows Machine. What is the procedure to host the app on my windows machine publicly. [Bokeh version 0.12.0]
(Please Don't Suggest for VM)

Comment: please provide reason for downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Solution
on Windows open cmd and run

```
cd C:\Python27\Scripts
```

then

```
bokeh serve C:\Users\your-path\File_name.py --address=0.0.0.0 --host *
```

This is working for me.